# Javascript function to check if string is a valid date

Tags: javascript, c#, validation, datetime-format, isodate

I know this has been asked several times, but I am asking because after scouring the internet for several hours, I have not found a viable solution that does not include using a Javascript library.

I am simply looking for a way to test whether or not a string is a valid date. I am binding data in Javascript passed from C# (JSON.NET). The format of a valid datetime that is being passed back is '2083-01-01T00:00:00'. All of the functions I have found either say this is invalid, because they are not including the timestamp portion as allowable, or they are not strict enough, and say that this string, 'Testing 21215', is a valid date.

What is a solution that I could use to validate this format, without using a library?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `new Date(valueInQuestion)`?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, I have. new Date('Testing 21215') will return a date. Which is not what I want.

Comment: I see. What values the Date constructor is able to recognize varies wildly between JS implementations. If you want a predictable, dependable  result, using a library becomes all but unavoidable.

Comment: @Tomalak I find it hard to believe that something seemingly so trivial as this should require a library, but after searching so much, you may be right. :(

Comment: Have you considered a validation framework like [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method/)?

Comment: @jrummell I would prefer not to implement a library or framework.

Comment: That's because you assume that date handling must be trivial. It's not, quite the contrary. In addition to the wide range of JS engines, there is a wide range of possible date representations. There is no such thing as "a valid date" - there is only a list of representations that you are willing to accept. You can't say what's valid without limiting acceptable inputs. Assuming the baseline should be ISO 8601 then I would make a regex for format checking and when a string matches, pass it to `new Date()` for validity checking.

Comment: @user2023116 then you'll have to do it the hard way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are guaranteeing that the format will always be in that ISO standard format, then you can use a regular expression to test the structure as a string. You can get crazy detailed with this if you want, or try the following.

```
var dateRegexp = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/
var matches = dateString.match(dateRegexp)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

There might be other drastically different approaches as well. My preferred way is to try and use the new Date(string) method; if this parses correctly, then you can convert it back to the ISO string

```
var dateString = "2016-03-18T00:00:00";
var date = new Date(dateString);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

However, you might need to be aware of the implications of this for international users.

Comment: I may end up going with this if no one else has a more flexible solution. I think for my circumstance, I can probably safely say that if it not in ISO format, then it isn't something I want to be recognized as valid.

Comment: Just to clarify my earlier comment, the regex is what I would implement. The new Date approach does not work, because it will coerce the string "Testing 21215" into a date, which is not what I want.

Comment: Right, that's clear. It's not a very good solution anyway, but you can still use that to normalize the datetime string if it passes the regexp tests.